# How to make this not move when you zoom in (the text and the image)?

Tags: html, css

How to make this not move when you zoom in (the text and the image)?
I tried and even looked up some tutorials and I can't rezolve the problem.
Can someone help me please, I don't know how to make this. And if you have suggestion for the UI, you can write that to.

Here is my HTML code
HTML=

```
<body>
    <div id="game">
    <h1>Clicker Game</h1>
    <img id="clicker"
    src="Images/Cursor.png"
    alt="Clicking Cursor">
    </div>

    <div id="moneybar">
        <p id="money">Money:</p>

    </div>

    <div id="upgrades">
        

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code
CSS=

```
h1 {
    font-size: 300%;
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    text-align: center;
}

#game {
    height: 85%;
    width: 85%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

#clicker {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 30%;
}

#upgrades {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-color: grey;
    border-width: 5%;
    border-style: solid;
}

#moneybar {
    width: 100%;
    Height: 15%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    border-color: grey;
    border-width: 5%;
    border-style: solid;
}

#money {
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example with codepen.io maybe? It'll be easier to review your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Modified version. I hope this is what you were looking for

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  text-align: center;
}

#game {
  height: 85%;
  width: 85%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Prevent content from overflowing */
}

#clicker {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
}

#upgrades {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 5%;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Add scrollbar if content overflows */
}

#moneybar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 5%;
  border-style: solid;
}

#money {
  font-size: 200%;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <h1>Clicker Game</h1>
  <img id="clicker" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Clicking Cursor">
  <!-- Change the image source. I am using from internet for testing purpose -->
</div>

<div id="moneybar">
  <p id="money">Money:</p>

</div>

<div id="upgrades">


</div>
```

PS: Change the `<img>` source in your code

Comment: And what img source should I use? (not on internet)

Comment: What Man? in your code you have this `<img id="clicker"
    src="Images/Cursor.png"
    alt="Clicking Cursor">`. Correct. I have used internet image source (`src`)